# Object oriented design: polymorphic classes with different dependencies?

Tags: dependency-injection, polymorphism

I don't have much experience with object oriented programming and design, so please bear with me.

I am trying to create a set of polymorphic DataProcessor classes. A DataProcessor has a set of data, and a process method. Each implementation can process the data in a completely different manner. For example writing to a database, sending an email, posting the data to an API, etc.

I'm confused about how to properly deal with all these different (and unknown) dependencies. I could just hard code the dependencies into each implementation and I think all should work fine, but is there a better design?

Comment: it it the processing that is different, or the handling of the results once processed (the examples you use don't sound like different processing (with databases and email and APIs etc))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better design is to require the different dependencies in the constructor of each different type, and just implement the interface to provide the common stuff.

```
public interface IDataProcessor 
{
     void ProcessData(SomeType data);
}
```

then your emailing implementation looks like this

```
public EmailingDataProcessor : IDataProcessor
{    
     IEmailer emailer;

     EmailingDataProcessor(IEmailer emailer)
     {
          this.emailer = emailer;
     }

     public void ProcessData(SomeType data)
     {
         //do the processing
         emailer.EmailResults();
     }
}
```

Repeat for each class with different dependencies.

This makes each class testable in its own right, and allows you to use the dependency inversion principal to provide the implementations of the dependencies.

If each processor shares some code (ie the processing is the same its just the delivery mechanism that differs then have a base class with the common code in and have this have an abstract method which can deliver the results. Then each different class can implement the abstract method to deliver the results differently, using the different dependencies and you don't duplicate the processing logic.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, and its close to what I had in mind. The only concern I see with doing this is that now I have to know which type of DataProcessor I am instantiating, because I need to pass in the dependency. Lets say I can have multiple different configurations that would only be known at run time, how can I instantiate only the ones I need in a dynamic fashion? If the dependencies are hard coded this is easy, I just take the class names specified in the configuration and instantiate them.

Comment: @MattJam you need to know which type you are instantiating that's true, but you need to know that in any case. As you point out the only difference is whether you need to have all the dependencies available at the point of instantiation. With your current plan you don't need the dependencies as they are hard coded, so you can happily `new EmaiingDataProcessor()` and you are away. This has drawbacks though as what happens when someone tells you you need to change the email address, or the message format? Or that you now need to use the `DatabaseDataProcessor()`. All this hard coding will bite..

Comment: you in the... What I would suggest is that you read up about the dependency inversion principal and inversion of control and instead of `new()`ing up your classes where you need them you instead declare them as dependencies through the constructor and pass them into the classes that need them from outside. Then you'll repeat this process again and again until you are right at the outside of your application (your `Main` method probably) where you will create your entire object graph. This is known as your composition root. Taking this approach will give you much more flexible, testable code

Comment: and will allow you to change your application by reconfiguring things rather than rewriting things when requirements change.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also i think a dependency container may be part of the answer to my second question.

Comment: a dependency container can help with the wiring up, but be aware that using the pattern and using a container to help automate things are two different things, and you don't need the container in order to do it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Provided that all DataProcessor implementations process the same type of data, you can use hierarchy.

```
public interface DataProcessor {
    public abstract void process(DataType data);
}

public class DatabaseDataProcessor implements DataProcessor {
    private MyDAO myDao;

    @Override
    public void process(DataType data) {

    }
}

public class EmailDataProcessor implements DataProcessor {
    private EmailSender sender;

    @Override
    public void process(DataType data) {

    }
}
```

There is no problem in injecting different dependencies in the implementations